# MYSQL exclude row if a value in specific column is a duplicate

Tags: mysql

I have a table of restaurant data and would like to remove rows in `restaurant_name` if they are duplicates when I `SELECT`. The only column I need checked for duplicates is `restaurant_name` I need to include all other columns as seen in the table.

I have tried `SELECT restaurant_id, max(restaurant_name), city FROM restaurant_data GROUP BY name` however it gives me `MYSQL error 1055: this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. After trying to change this setting, the query worked, however it is slow

Is there a better way of doing this or should I just keep that setting disabled?

Table:

```
restaurant_id  |  restaurant_name  |  city   |   5 other columns  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                 Rest1               A            strings
  2                 Rest1               B            strings
  3                 Rest2               C            strings
  4                 Rest3               C            strings
  5                 Rest1               D            strings
  6                 Rest2               D            strings
  7                 Rest3               C            strings
```

Desired Results:

```
restaurant_id  |  restaurant_name  |  city   |   5 other columns  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1                 Rest1               A            strings
  3                 Rest2               C            strings
  4                 Rest3               C            strings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` on MySQL 8+:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY restaurant_name
                                 ORDER BY restaurant_id) rn
    FROM restaurant_data
)

SELECT restaurant_id, restaurant_name, city
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Otherwise, on earlier versions of MySQL, we can join your table to a subquery which finds the lowest `restaurant_id` for each name:

```sql
SELECT r1.restaurant_id, r1.restaurant_name, r1.city
FROM restaurant_data r1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT restaurant_name, MIN(restaurant_id) AS min_restaurant_id
    FROM restaurant_date
    GROUP BY restaurant_name
) r2
    ON r2.restaurant_name = r1.restaurant_name AND
       r2.min_restaurant_id = r1.restaurant_id;
```

Comment: I have mySQL 7 and the bottom code block worked perfectly. Big ups

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of mysql then you can use rank function for this.

```
SELECT restaurant_id, restaurant_name, city FROM
(
    select restaurant_id, restaurant_name, city , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY restaurant_name order by restaurant_id)ranks
    from restaurant_data
) T WHERE ranks=1;
```

Comment: This solution works, however I made the other answer as correct as it took half as long to complete the operation (0.1 seconds as apposed to 0.3s for a table of 70,000 records)